# java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine

Tags: java, properties, nullpointerexception, apache-storm

I am running **Apache storm** topology and I am trying to read the values from properties file. My main function is able to read the values while the bolts are throwing the following error.

Also , I am able to read all the values from a normal class in the same project.

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434) at 
java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) at 
java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) at 
com.StormConsumer.commons.FilePropertyManager.loadPrope
rtyFile(FilePropertyManager.java:54) at 
com.StormConsumer.commons.FilePropertyManager.getProper
ty(FilePropertyManager.java:34) at 
com.StormConsumer.bolt.SessionIdCounter.prepare(SessionIdCounter.java:42) at 
backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.prepare(BasicBoltExecutor.java:43) 
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4722$fn__4734.invoke(executor.clj:692) 
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__458.invoke(util.clj:461) at 
clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to solve it ?

**This is the class :**

```
public class SessionIdCounter extends BaseBasicBolt {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Cluster cluster;
Session session;

/*private static final String KEYSPACE = FilePropertyManager.getProperty(
        ApplicationConstants.CASSANDRA_CONSTANTS_FILE,
        ApplicationConstants.KEYSPACE);
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = FilePropertyManager.getProperty(
        ApplicationConstants.CASSANDRA_QUERY_FILE,
        ApplicationConstants.TABLE_SessionID);*/

/**
 * creates a table SessionID with fields sessionid, year, month, day, hour,
 * dayofyear, weekofyear, count.
 */

public void cleanup() {

}

public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context) {
    final String KEYSPACE = FilePropertyManager.getProperty(
            ApplicationConstants.CASSANDRA_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.KEYSPACE);
    final String CREATE_TABLE = FilePropertyManager.getProperty(
            ApplicationConstants.CASSANDRA_QUERY_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.TABLE_SessionID);

    cluster = CassandraConnection.setupCassandraClient();
    session = CassandraConnection.getSessionWithRetry(cluster, KEYSPACE);

    session.executeAsync(CREATE_TABLE);
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
}

public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {

    String sessionid = input.getString(0);
    int year = input.getInteger(1);
    int month = input.getInteger(2);
    int day = input.getInteger(3);
    int hour = input.getInteger(4);
    int dayofyear = input.getInteger(5);
    int weekofyear = input.getInteger(6);

    /*
     * Inserting Values In Cassandra
     */

    String insertUpdateTable = "UPDATE SessionID SET count = count + 1 "
            + "where sessionid = \'" + sessionid + "\' AND year = " + year
            + " AND month = " + month + " AND day = " + day
            + " AND hour = " + hour + " AND dayofyear = " + dayofyear
            + " AND weekofyear = " + weekofyear + " ;";
    session.executeAsync(insertUpdateTable);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your property file. If the `ApplicationConstants.CASSANDRA_CONSTANTS_FILE` points to a local file not avalaible in all your server, then you've got a problem. Also, check the format of your file.

Comment: ApplicationConstants.CASSANDRA_CONSTANTS_FILE gives the name of the properties file while ApplicationConstants.TABLE_SessionID fetches the value. I didn't get your point regarding local file not available in servers. How to configure it to run on cluster?

Comment: Your bolt will be running on multiple servers ? So server1 and server2 must have the file avalaible, if not you will have some problems. Why you just don't put your properties into a table in your DB ? You can also put our property file into the jar you send to Storm.

Comment: Currently I am running my topology on a single machine. My properties files are in src/main/resources/. I am using `mvn compile` and `mvn package` to build the jar .So, I guess it will put the properties file into the jar file. Am I correct or do i need to include something else ?

Comment: Normally, it you use resource in your jar, you should do like myClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("pathafterResource/myFile.xml"); Also, open your jar to make sur the file is there

Comment: putting properties file in jar worked for me.Had to edit my pom.xml to include all the properties file in jar.Thanks a lot !!